# using any utility pip/awscli is throwing error on ubuntu linux system

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip

Team, I have issues using any utility like pip or awscli. any hint how can I fix this?

```
# python --version
Python 2.7.12

root@dtl# pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands.completion import CompletionCommand
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/completion.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.base_command import Command
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pip._internal.download import PipSession
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import requests, six, urllib3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 97, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 118, in <module>
    SSL_ST_INIT = _lib.SSL_ST_INIT
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'
```